# SSL\TLS support in Play 2.2.1

Tags: ssl, playframework, playframework-2.0, ssl-certificate

I'm having a Play! (2.2.1, Java) Application and I want to allow:

- Client Side Certificates - Only client authentication using a client side certificate can use the application API.
- Server Side Certificates – Clients must be able to authenticate the certificate presented by the server via their trusted list of CAs.

What are Play! best practices for doing that?

In addition, do you know what cryptographic algorithm Play! is using? (TLS 1.2, 1.1, 1.0, SSL 3.0, SSL 2.0, etc.) and if it's not using TLS 1.2, can I enforce Play! to use it?

When you are using SSL/TLS for Play!  What do you use for front end HTTPS Server?. Apache, Nginx, Netty.IO or Play! Build in the server? (Because according to the official documentation, the non Play! servers can handle HTTPS request better).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play uses JSSE for TLS, so you configure Play using the SSLEngine that comes with JSSE.  If you are using Play as an HTTPS client, then WS will do the hostname verification for you.  If you're using Play as an HTTPS server and need to do client authentication, you should configure a custom SSLEngineProvider.

There is an activator template that shows how to use Play as both HTTPS client and server, using client authentication:

https://github.com/typesafehub/activator-play-tls-example